# Instantiate CompositeContainer in MEF module dll

Tags: dependency-injection, mef

Wondering where/how to instantiate dependency injection in a MEF module dll assembly? Following the Caliburn.Micro HelloScreens example. Have pulled out the individually exported IWorkspace implementations into seperate MEF module DLLS.

I'm specifically referring to module specific dependency injection. May not be necessary for my simple first project, but looking for proper way to instantiate dependency injection in a dll project.

Entry point into the DLL appears to be CustomersWorkspaceViewModel ...

Options I see, and I'm fresh to modular programming, is

## 1 - to instantiate CompositeContainer in CustomerWorkspaceViewModel constructor

or

## 2 - Wait until the module is activated and then instantiate.

or

## 3 - Your suggestions

Could not find examples or best practices using my google abilities...